# How do I skip specific tests when building an rpm?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am building an RPM of git version 2.13.0. The build has gone ok but one of the tests are failing:

```
Config variable ${LIB_HTTPD_SVN} is not defined
Config variable ${LIB_HTTPD_SVN_PATH} is not defined
```

I cannot find any info about these variables so I was going to just skip the tests. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the spec file to identify where tests are executed.

For instance, I am using git2u and I have the same problem.
In order to disable tests, I reviewed the spec file and identified that tests are executed in `%check`.

https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/git2u/blob/2.15.1-1/SPECS/git2u.spec

So, to skip check I run `rpmbuild` with the option `--nocheck`

Comment: Older versions (RPM < v4.10) of `rpmbuild` don't support that option. Amending any problematic check(s) to something like `make test || true` in the `.spec` file is a cheap and not-too-nasty workaround (and allows you to see the scale of any potential problems during the run).